# IE8 blur filter on a canvas

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas, filter, blur

I've got a canvas that works thanks to Google's `excanvas` in IE. Now I want to blur the thing. 
I added a blur filter with the IE propertiary syntax and it blurred the canvas and the text inside a div.

Well... It did work in IE7 and IE9, but **not** in IE8. [WTF?!]

Hope somebody have seen that before.

I also tried to enable the blur from javascript after drawing on the canvas, but it didn't change anything.

Here's a live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rd9q5/1/embedded/result/

*The example is only the IE code. It won't work in other browsers, but my main code does.*

I put an interesting image in the example for you to get amused while you help me. :)

[edit]

Generally blur works in IE8 - I put some text at the bottom of the div in my example page and the text gets blurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the 'position:absolute' specified on g_vml_:shape produced by excanvas.js line 597

### Why?!...

Because there's a BUG in IE8 that elements with position other than static will not inherit filters of parent element, unless we do that.

To fix this do one of the following options

```
function go() {
    var browser = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(msie) ([\w.]+)/);
    if(document.styleSheets['ex_canvas_'] && browser && browser[2].slice(0,1) == '8'){
        var stylesheet = document.createStyleSheet();
        stylesheet.owningElement.id = 'ex_canvas_';
        stylesheet.cssText = '#cp *{filter:inherit;}';
    }
    // codes for draw
}
```

Or

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <style type="text/css">
         #cp *{
             filter:inherit;
         }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Looks promising. Is it a known bug with a publicly avaliable bug report, or you just happen to know that?

Comment: No, i just find out, its about shape tags(g_vml_:shape), actually i didn't have enough time to find about details.I'd searched about it and what i found was nothing.

Comment: I'll test it at home and if it works - it's a well earned bounty for you.

Comment: Thanks and i'm finding the real problem for you, and just for fun: i just stop working on a project for some kind of government companies.its in my blood to find out about anything... :)

Comment: Both methods work. I have no idea how you figured that out :). Huge thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article. It's a long winded way but may help.

http://aautar.digital-radiation.com/blog/?p=2519

More:

- http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blur/
- [How to draw a blurry circle on HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475755/how-to-draw-a-blurry-circle-on-html5-canvas)
- [Blur show effect - html5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451187/blur-show-effect-html5-canvas)

Comment: IE8 doesn't support canvas. I am using code derived from pixastic fastblur in supporting browsers already. HTML5 canvas doesn't work in IE8. I use excanvas from google to draw on a canvas simulation that doesn't have methods allowing to get image and work with pixels.

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that IE8 doesn't support canvas. Didn't know that excanvas doesn't have those methods.

Comment: There's a note in the comments inside excanvas.js that says what it lacks. It's quite informative. +1 for mentioning pixastic, which has the fastest blur I could find (`fastBlur`)

Answer (score 0):

Because Microsoft dumped 'filter' after IE7 so I'm surprised you say it works in IE9.

Comment: No, it didn't. The filter works in IE8 and 9, but it doesn't blur the canvas for some reasom. In my example there's a bit of text at the bottom "this gets blurred" that is blured by every IE